# Define a decorator guard in typescript

Tags: typescript, reflect-metadata

Imagine that you have classes that implement a certain decorator:

```
@Component
class A

@Component
class B
```

If you want to have a variable that holds the class itself of some of this classes, what type would it have?

```
componentClass: typeof A | typeof B;
```

But has you already may be thinking: enumerating the classes is not good practice when you have a lot of them, and it's not even an option when you don't know them all.

So the option that remains is *(edit: because typescript doesn't allow typeof generics)*:

```
componentClass: any;
```

But this isn't good either!

---

**I want to define a type guard for this**, so I can replace the `any` type from one that can actually check if the object has the @Component decorator, so it can be declared like this:

```
componentClass: ComponentClass;
```

---

### Just an idea

The best way I think is to define a type for it, and in there define the guard. ***But this is not possible***.

```
@HasDecorator("Component")
type ComponentClass = any;
```

---

### *Hope to see your ideas to solve this. Thanks!*

Comment: You can't do that. Decorators are functions that get invoked at runtime, while the type system is for compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have different classes that represent a `Component`, then why don't you have a base class for them all:

```
abstract class ComponentClass { ... }

@Component
class A extends ComponentClass { ... }

@Component
class B extends ComponentClass { ... }
```

Then you have a type for all those classes and there's no need for the type aliasing.
It can also be useful for the decorator itself:

```
function Component(ctor: { new(): ComponentClass }) {}
```

Or even:

```
function Component<T extends ComponentClass>(ctor: { new(): T }) {}
```

---

#### Edit

You can also do something similar with an interface of course:

```
interface ComponentClass { }

@Component
class A implements ComponentClass { }

@Component
class B implements ComponentClass { }
```

---

#### 2nd Edit

If you want to pass a `ComponentClass` (`A`, or `B`, etc) then you can do:

```
function fn(cls: typeof ComponentClass) { ... }

fn(A);
```

Or

```
function fn<T extends ComponentClass>(cls: { new(): T }) { ... }

fn(B);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20Component%3CT%20extends%20ComponentClass%3E(ctor%3A%20%7B%20new()%3A%20T%20%7D)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20ComponentClass%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%40Component%0D%0Aclass%20A%20extends%20ComponentClass%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%40Component%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20ComponentClass%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20fn1%3CT%20extends%20ComponentClass%3E(cls%3A%20%7B%20new()%3A%20T%20%7D)%20%7B%20%20%7D%0D%0Afn1(B)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20fn2(cls%3A%20typeof%20ComponentClass)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Afn2(A)%3B))

Comment: Please check my edit. I said the variable *holds the class itself*, but forgot to add *typeof* to the declaration, like this: `componentClass: typeof A`. Your suggestion was my first approach too, but **typescript doesn't support typeof generics**, so I can't do it.

Comment: Why do you need `typeof A`? How would you use that?

Comment: To be able to pass `A` to a function, instead of an instance of it. I dynamically create components and need to know the class of each one to create, so I need to pass a type.

Comment: Won't that give the error `Argument of type 'typeof A' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof ComponentClass'`? That's the *typeof generic* I was talking about. If you don't have that error, then a recent version of typescript added support for it.

Comment: I haven't used `typeof` at all in my code. Added a link to the code in playground. In anycase, you shouldn't be getting errors if you do that.

Comment: Ok so my error should be because of other reason. I'll mark this as the correct answer. Thank's for your help!

Comment: If you still get an error, add the problematic code to your question, I'll take a look at it.